# How to manually authenticate user

Tags: python, django

I want to authenticate user manually
how can I keep user signed in, in all applications of project?
Here's my login view function:

```
def sign(request):
    context = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SigninForm(data = request.POST)
        if form.is_valid:
            username = request.POST['username']
            password = hashlib.sha256(request.POST['password'].encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
            users = customer.objects.all()          
            for user in users:
                if username == user.username:
                    if password == user.password:
                        context['tmp'] = "OK"
```

Comment: Django has a [built-in full authentication system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/), for what I read on your example, you're not using it, so you'll need to a) start using it or b) code your own session control, which is probably something you'd rather not do.

Comment: Let's go stronger. **You must not** write your own authentication system. Here although you are hashing passwords you are not doing so securely. This is absolutely a security risk; do not do this under any circumstances. Just use Django's built in auth.

Answer (score 0):

Django has a built-in authentication system. Read more about it in [User authentication in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/).

However, you can customize it or rewrite it completely (use your own logic). Read more about it in [Customizing authentication in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/).